# send user back to a particular part of the previous page after functions complete using header?

Tags: php, mysql

does anyone know if i can get header in php to take a user to a certain point on a page when a form has been submitted and a function has finished and then it redirects a person back to a certain part of that page?

this is my if result:

```
 $_SESSION['message_sent']="<div class=\"message_sent\"></div>"; 
header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
```

it currently takes the user back to the page they was on but i want the user to be taken to the middle of the page?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try doing as following, take for eg : "test" is the "name" attribute of anchor tag on the page :

HTML CODE :

```
<a name="test"></a>
    <div>
     .......
    </div>
```

PHP CODE :

```
$path = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."#test";

header("Location:$path");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with having links within a page this should be simple.

You basically have your URL and append the `id` of the HTML element you want the page to go to when it loads. For example a URL like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php#about
```

Would take you to the following element on the index.php page:

```
<div id="about"></div>
```

Comment: yes but im not sure this works with php header function does it?